# Mysql - How to compare date (mm/dd/yyyy) with another another date from database?

Tags: mysql, date, datetime

This is my SELECT query

> season_from_date >= "06/09/2015" and season_to_date <=
>   "06/11/2015"

The same date format(mm/dd/yyyy), am saving in my database. I am not getting error but its not showing any result? Is that correct method or do we have any other method?

Comment: what is the data type of column `'season_from_date'`?

Comment: What is it you are trying to do? It's not clear. Where is the select query?

Comment: @RavinderReddy I used varchar :(

Comment: SELECT * FROM `tbl_hotel` `h` JOIN `tbl_hotelrate` `thr` ON thr.int_hotelId = h.int_hotel_id JOIN `tbl_city` `tc` ON tc.int_city_id = h.int_city_id JOIN `tbl_states` `ts` ON ts.int_state_id = h.int_state_id JOIN `tbl_amenities` `ta` ON ta.int_type_id = h.int_hotel_id WHERE (((((`h`.`bit_active` LIKE 1 and `h`.`int_city_id` LIKE 19) AND (thr.season_from_date >= "06/09/2015" and thr.season_to_date <= "06/11/2015")) AND (h.int_hotelcatId = "98")) AND (h.int_totalRoom >= "1")) AND (thr.int_child_room >= 1)) AND (thr.int_personRoom >= 1) ORDER BY `h`.`int_hotel_id` DESC

Answer (score 2):

You should never store in those format and using varchar field, you should always store date data with mysql native datatypes this makes life easy. However in this case you may use `str_to_date` function

```
select * from table_name 
where 
str_to_date(season_from_date,'%m/%d/%Y') between
str_to_date('06/09/2015','%m/%d/%Y') 
and
str_to_date('06/11/2015','%m/%d/%Y')
```